# PowerShell to copy files to destination's subfolders while excluding certain folders in the destination

Tags: powershell, xcopy, get-childitem, copy-item

So I have danced with this off and on throughout the day and the timeless phrase "There's more than one way to skin a cat" keeps coming to mind so I decided to take to the community.

Scenario:

Source folder *"C:\Updates"* has 100 files of various extensions.  All need to be copied to the ***sub-folders only*** of *"C:\Prod\"* overwriting any duplicates that it may find.

The Caveats:

1. The sub-folder names (destinations) in *"C:\Prod"* are quite dynamic and change frequently.
2. A naming convention is used to determine which sub-folders in the destination need to be excluded when the source files are being copied (to retain the original versions).  For ease of explanation lets say any folder names starting with "!stop" should be excluded from the copy process. (!stop* if wildcards considered)

So, here I am wanting the input of those greater than I to tackle this in PS if I'm lucky.  I've tinkered with Copy-Item and xcopy today so I'm excited to hear other's input.

Thanks!

-Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Prod -Exclude !stop* -Directory `
| ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path C:\Updates\* -Destination $_ -Force }
```

This grabs each folder (the `-Directory` switch ensures we only grab folders) in C:\Prod that does not match the filter and pipes it to the `ForEach-Object` command where we are running the `Copy-Item` command to copy the files to the directory.

The `-Directory` switch is not available in every version of PowerShell; I do not know which version it was introduced in off the top of my head.  If you have an older version of PowerShell that does not support `-Directory` then you can use this script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Prod -Exclude !stop* `
| Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } `
| ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path C:\Updates\* -Destination $_ -Force }
```

Comment: That got it!  I had no clue about the -Destination switch and sure enough I opened ISE on my Windows 10 VM and BOOM there it was.  Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: From [Get-ChildItem for FileSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/providers/filesystem-provider/get-childitem-for-filesystem#notes): "The Attributes, Directory, File, Hidden, ReadOnly, and System parameters were introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0 and are effective only in file system drives."

Answer (score 0):

To select only sub folders which do not begin with "!stop" do this

```
$Source = "C:\Updates\*"
$Dest =   "C:\Prod"
$Stop =   "^!stop"

$Destinations = GCI -Path $Dest |?{$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -notmatch $Stop }
ForEach ($Destination in $Destinations) {
  Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Destination.FullName -Force 
}
```

**Edited** Now copies all files from Update to subs of Source not beginning with "!stop" The -whatif switch shows what would happen, to arm the script remove the -whatif.

**Edit2** Streamlined the script. If also Sub/sub-folders of C:\Prod shall receive copies include a -rec option to the gci just in front of he pipe.

Comment: Hi LotPings,  Your 1st 2 lines of code work as expected, but your last one  **ForEach ($Destination in $Destionations) { "do copy/compare" }**  is leaving me a little bit lost.  I appreciate your input greatly and would like to ask you to revise this so I can give you your due credit for posting!

Comment: They are only meant as a place holder for code supplied by yourself. Your Scenario is a bit  unclear in this aspect. Are files only copied if an older version exists, or all files. And the sentence in parentheses is a contradiction in itself. So I choose to concentrate on the main part.

Comment: @CharlieEcho Editt the answer to copy all files

Comment: YES!  Your input is very good.  This works perfectly.  I apologize about not being clear and have updated the question.